# Remove/Hide TinyMCE without removing formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How do I hide the editor by default and show it only when the user clicks "Show Editor"? 
Also the formatting of the text should not go when the editor is hidden. He/she should be able to make a text bold by selecting it and going a "Ctrl+B".
The example to hide the editor in TinyMCE website removes all formatting and shows the HTML version with all HTML tags when the editor is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for seems like the readonly-editor mode. Well, a user won't be able to edit contents, but you will keep the formating the same.

When the editor is hidden you will see a regular html elment like a textarea holding the created editor content. And of course there is no formating applied. The editor creates on initialization a contenteditable iframe and loads css inthe the iframes head. In order to show the editor contents formatted without the editor means you would have to create an iframe with loaded css and insert the content there. I am sorry, but there is no other solution.

**Update:** You could do something like

```
$('#' + your_editor_id + '_tbl '+'.mceToolbar').hide();
```

Comment: I have seen this implemented in [Moodle](http://moodle.org). Their latest version (2.5) has TinyMCE with functionality like this. I can install a demo moodle instance and give you access if you want to look at it. I tried to look at their code, but understood nothing.

Comment: yes, i would take a glimpse (but i giess they are doing just what i proposed)

Comment: Well, I found a public moodle demo server!
Login to [http://qa.moodle.net](http://qa.moodle.net) using username/password as teacher/test. Go to [this](http://qa.moodle.net/question/edit.php?cmid=59) page. A list of questions would be displayed. Click the gear icon in one of the question and have a look at the forms.

Comment: EDIT: The 1st question do not have the "show editing tools" thing. Check 2nd or 3rd question.

Comment: hmm, i think i did not find what you mean

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot for your reference. [http://i42.tinypic.com/2mhbdk7.jpg](http://i42.tinypic.com/2mhbdk7.jpg)

Comment: found it, but what you see there is an editor instance (even though the toolbar has been hidden)!!

Comment: Oh! So how do I do that? from outside the editor? That would answer my question!

Comment: you could do something like $('#' + your_editor_id + '_tbl '+'.mceToolbar').hide();

Comment: Thanks. I used $('#' + your_editor_id + '_tbl '+'.mceStatusbar').hide(); to hide the status bar as well! Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it as a solution?